# Не проходит авторизация curl

Tags: curl, php

Здравствуйте. Уже не знаю, что делать, кучу методов перепробовал, не происходит авторизация никак. (

```
   <?php
   $url= "https://steamcommunity.com/login/home/";
$curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookiefile"); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; ru; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824 Firefox/3.5.3'); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://steamcommunity.com/login/home/'); 
    $html = curl_exec($curl);

    preg_match('/<input type="hidden" id="login_csrf" value="(.*)"/Uis',$html, $login_csrf);

    $login_csrf = $login_csrf[1];

    //echo $login_csrf;

    $post = "username=test&password=test123&remember=1&formid=login";

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://steamcommunity.com/login/home/');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    $html = curl_exec($curl);
    echo $html;
    ?>
```

Comment: @Сергей Румянцев, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем понимаю, для чего Вам нужен CURL, если есть [Steam Web API](http://steamcommunity.com/dev?l=russian). Регистрируемся, получаем [API Key](http://steamcommunity.com/dev/apikey). Далее 2 варианта, либо работаем с API посредством XML/JSON, либо используем [steam-api-php](https://github.com/DaMitchell/steam-api-php) класс. Но, насколько я понял, Вы собираетесь заниматься, чем-то не совсем легальным... И вот вам отличная статья по теме: [Немного о Steam Web Api](http://habrahabr.ru/post/172223/).

Comment: Есть четкий вопрос, нужен ответ на него! А не об других методах, которые не относятся к тому, что мне нужно!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить проанализировать в браузере, посмотреть какие заголовки отсылаются и вполне возможно что нужно просто добавить REFERER